# How to get information of particular user from facebook,twitter,google?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a web app in java like following

the user enters his/her mail id and password if the user mail id and password are same in

```
Facebook
Twitter
Google
Buzz
LinkedIn
```

than fetch the information like post and twit etc which belong to that user. I googled and found that sociallib provides the solution but could not get it exactly. so provide me some good examples

Comment: You want the user to enter their username and password for one service, and then you try to log them in to other services with the same username and password? Doesn't that seem a bit... creepy... to you?

Comment: You used to be able to do this, at least for Twitter, but I believe they have removed the ability to log in "automatically". The API now requires the user to be redirected to the twitter login and to approve your application .

Comment: You got the problem but i think it is not creepy. It is the way we make user feel comfortable to get the information by not using other services. by the way it is my own app i just want to try. Hope you can also help me to get that.

Comment: User can be allowed to user one service as you said, after using one service the application has to check with other services if the credentials are correct than fetch the details and show

Answer (score 0):

Fetching Facebook/Twitter data by using a username and password is impossible.

To fetch data from Twitter or Facebook, you need to create an application using an SDK, for example the PHP or JS SDK. Users must connect their account to your application, while connecting they give you permission to obtain the requested data.

Facebook PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
Information about how to use this SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Twitter PHP SDK: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth
Information about how to use this SDK:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api